# Use data populated by useEffect in conditional useSWR

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I'm trying to resolve [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74619266/11020164), and I'm almost there. I'm getting the correct data from the API, and it's updating when it should, but on initial load `useSWR` is hitting the API with all `null` data.

The data come from `useContext`, and are set in a `useEffect` hook in a parent of the component that calls `useSWR`.

I guess what's happening is that the since `useEffect` isn't called until after initial hydration, the component with `useSWR` is being rendered before it has data.

But if the context setter isn't wrapped in a `useEffect`, I get

`` Warning: Cannot update a component (`ContestProvider`) while rendering a different component (`PageLandingPage`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `PageLandingPage`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render ``

and it's stuck in an infinite loop.

<s>I could probably stop this by putting some checks in the fetcher, but that seems like a hack to me. The [`useSWR` documentation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started) addresses the case of fetching data server side and making it available to multiple components right in the Getting Started section, but what's the correct way to get data from the *client* that needs to be used in multiple components, including ones that want to fetch data from the server based on the client data?</s>

**EDIT**: Since originally asking the question, I've discovered [conditional fetching](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching), and the third option there seems nearly a perfect fit, but I'm using a complex key to a custom fetcher, and the data for the key aren't coming from another `useSWR` call, as  in the example — they're coming from the `useContext` which has the unfortunate difference that, unlike the example, the data are `null` instead of `undefined`, so it won't `throw`.

How can I use this conditionality with data coming in from the `useContext`?

Here's the app hierarchy:

```
<MyApp>
  <ContestEntryPage>
    <ContestProvider> // context provider
      <PageLandingPage> // sets the context
        <Section>
          <GridColumn>
            <DatoContent>
              <ContestPoints> // calls useSWR with data from the context
```

Here's the `useSWR` call:

```
// /components/ContestPoints.js
const fetcher = async ({pageId, contestId, clientId}) => {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/getpoints?pageId=${pageId}&clientId=${clientId}&contestId=${contestId}`);

    if (!res.ok) {
        const error = new Error('A problem occured getting contest points');
        error.info = await res.json();
        error.status = res.status;

        throw error;
    }

    return res.json();
}

const ContestPoints = () => {
    const { contestState } = useContest();

    // XXX should be conditional on the `contestState` parameters    
    const { data: points, error } = useSWR({
        pageId: contestState.pageId,
        contestId: contestState.contestId,
        clientId: contestState.clientId
    }, fetcher);

    if (error) {
        logger.warn(error, `Problem getting contest points: ${error.status}: ${error.info}`);
    }

    return (
        <p>{points?.points || 'Loading...'}</p>
    )
}

export default ContestPoints
```

It seems like finding a way to make that do the conditional fetching is likely best, but in case it's more elegant to leave the `useSWR` call as is, and address this farther up the chain, here are the other relevant pieces of code.

The context is being set based on information in `localStorage`:

```
// /components/PageLandingPage.js
import { useContest } from '../utils/context/contest';

const PageLandingPage = ({ data }) => {
    const { dispatchContest } = useContest(); // wrapper around useContext which uses useReducer

    useEffect(() => {
        // Don't waste the time if we're not a contest page
        if (!data?.contestPage?.id) return;

        const storedCodes = getItem('myRefCodes', 'local'); //utility function to retrieve from local storage
        const refCodes = storedCodes ? JSON.parse(storedCodes)?.refCodes : [];

        const registration = refCodes
            .map((code) => {
                const [ contestId, clientId ] = hashids.decode(code);
                return {
                    contestId: contestId,
                    clientId: clientId
                }
            })
            .find((reg) => reg.contestId && reg.clientId)

        dispatchContest({
            payload: {
                pageId: data.contestPage.id,
                contestId: registration.contestId,
                clientId: registration.clientId,
                registrationUrl: landingPage?.registrationPage?.slug || ''
            },
            type: 'update'
        })
    }, [data, dispatchContest])
    ...
```

And the context wrapper is initialising with `null` state:

```
const initialState = { 
    contestId: null,
    clientId: null
};
const ContestContext = createContext(initialState);

function ContestProvider({ children }) {
    const [contestState, dispatchContest] = useReducer((contestState, action) => {
        return {
            ...contestState,
            ...action.payload
        }
    }, initialState);

    return (
        <ContestContext.Provider value={{ contestState, dispatchContest }}>
            {children}
        </ContestContext.Provider>
    );
}

function useContest() {
    const context = useContext(ContestContext);

    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error('useContest was used outside of its provider');
    }

        return context;
}

export { ContestProvider, useContest }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's the best solution, but I ended up resolving this by using the first example in [the documentation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching), using `null` and a new field in the `context`:

```
const { data: points, error } = useSWR(contestState?.isSet ? {
        pageId: contestState.pageId,
        contestId: contestState.contestId,
        clientId: contestState.clientId
    } : null, fetcher);
```

and the `contestState.isSet` gets set in the `context`:

```
const initialState = { 
    isSet: false,
    contestId: null,
    clientId: null
};
```

and update it when all the other fields get set:

```
dispatchContest({
            payload: {
                isSet: true,
                pageId: data.contestPage.id,
                contestId: registration.contestId,
                clientId: registration.clientId,
                registrationUrl: landingPage?.registrationPage?.slug || ''
            },
            type: 'update'
        })
```